# Debugging JavaScript errors in Internet Explorer on Vista with UAC enabled

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, debugging, internet-explorer, windows-vista

Consider the following trivial HTML page that throws an error:

```
<html><head><script>
  throw new Error('oops');
  alert('should not reach here');
</script></head></html>
```

The user I am logged into Vista with is a member of both the Administrators and Debugger Users groups.

If I run Internet Explorer on Vista as an administrator (right click → **Run as administrator**) and load the page I get the following error prompt:

[image]

Clicking Yes displays the following prompt from which I can successfully open Visual Studio 2008 and debug the problem:

[alt text http://img227.imageshack.us/img227/9751/debuguy3.png](http://img227.imageshack.us/img227/9751/debuguy3.png)

If I instead launch Internet Explorer normally and load the page no error prompt is displayed (or any indication of the error for that matter) and I can't jump in and debug the problem.

I've tried making the site the page is served from a trusted site in Internet Explorer. This causes the error prompt to be displayed for the page, but clicking yes doesn't do anything and the browser just sits and hangs.

Similarly I can only successfully attach to an existing Internet Explorer process from Visual Studio to debug JavaScript if Internet Explorer was run as an administrator.

**How can I successfully debug JavaScript with Visual Studio when running Internet Explorer with UAC enabled?**

Comment: Just out of curiosity...why do you want to be able to debug the javascript in IE as an unprivileged use anyway? It seems that microsoft has it this way for a reason...The only reason I can see is because IE is so insecure that you don't even want to test in IE with all permissions.

Comment: ditto. I've tried developing in Vista as a non-admin user and it is painful.

Comment: I'm fine with elevating permissions for debugging, but I want run to as close as possible as normal users would when developing and testing. If an error occurs I want to debug it immediately rather than have to open an IE instance as an administrator and retrace the steps to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internet Explorer 8 comes with a built in debugger that neatly sidesteps this problem. This should reduce the time I need to spend debugging in earlier versions of Internet Explorer, so I can live with this annoyance until those versions go the way of the Dodo :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you gone into the Advanced Options in IE? I think the settings you are looking for are just turned off by default for normal users.

I could be mistaken though, I haven't been working with Vista much.

Edit: Let me rephrase: have you double-checked your settings under the limited account. Sometimes in an attempt to be "helpful" I've see where XP (or it might have been the security software) automatically changes some settings in the limited accounts.

I realize that your Admin account would have those on and that you are surely intelligent enough to check it on the Admin account. I was just suggesting that like many others, you might want to re-check the limited account.

Comment: Yes, my Internet Explorer advanced options are correctly configured, otherwise the debug prompt would not have appeared as noted when running Internet Explorer as administrator.

Comment: @Simon: IE stores per-user settings.  This is assuming that you didn't change your administrative user to a limited user, but I'd say it's a safe assumption.

Comment: I've realised my original question incorrectly described my situation. I'm not running as a limited user, but as an administrative user with UAC enabled. I've updated the question to correctly describe the situation. My apologies for any confusion caused.

Comment: I've also just gone and confirmed the debugging options are correctly set when running Internet Explorer normally and when running it with elevated privileges.